# Google Nearby messages API not working

Tags: android, google-beacon-platform

I have [registered](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register) a beacon and [attached](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/attachments) data using Google Proximity API. Next, I have written a test Android app to listen for beacons and subscribe messages created in my dev console. I have followed all steps documented [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7InjJGqP15E). The issue is that the onFound callback is never called.

```
 @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Found message: " + message);
        }
```

API info [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages)

Do I need any specific permissions within my AndroidMannifest.xml? 
I have only added a com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY meta-data attribute in my manifest.

Comment: I found an interesting video on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7InjJGqP15E It seems I need to use MessageFilter builder but it seems some methods described in the video are not available in Google Play Services 7.8 (client library version 26)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while I used Estimote Beacon. It appears by default it comes up with 'iBeacon' profile.

Based on my personal experience, iBeacon is not detected by NearBy API. I tried changing the beacon profile to 'EddyStone-beacon' and it started detecting.

Can you try changing the beacon profile to EddyStone and try?

Comment: I am using beacon from RadiousNetworks. Using the configuration app, I have already configured the beacon to transmit Eddystone UID.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `subscribe` to the messages for the beacons via attached data namespaces and types — all done via filters. This is [documented here at Google developers](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages)

One other key to not miss is that you must set the result callback with `setResultCallback`. Not setting seems to mean that your callbacks won't get called all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the nearby messages API without problems. I find this google example very interesting: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/blob/master/messages/NearbyDevices/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/samples/nearbydevices/MainFragment.java

Remember to change your subscribe options and set the strategy in this way: Strategy.BLE_ONLY

In your manifest you have to add only the Key, but rememeber to enable NearbyMessages API in your developer console.